# Why does the Normal reaction force vary in a straight line & curved path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

[image]

As visible from the above picture, the normal reaction force while ascending on an incline gradually decreases, however for a circular/curved path it increases. Intuitively, this seems wrong to me.

My question is:

> What is the significant difference in these two situations which is causing the Normal to increase/decrease respectively?

Comment: In first case, on what basis are you saying that normal reaction will decrease? Overall, the normal reaction (acting perpendicular to plane): $N=Mgcos\theta$, where $\theta$ is angle of inclination.

Comment: Uh when $\theta$ increases $cos\theta$ decreases.

Answer (score 1):

The normal reaction does not change along an incline of fixed slope- it remains constant. It varies on the circular path because the slope continuously varies.